# why is my endUpdates throwing an error (when it works in the same function)

Tags: swift

I have this function, which is called by a delegate from a cell.

It is calling this array:

```
var ingredientsArray = [String]()
```

I have this in the viewDidAppear(), not sure if this is related:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ingredientsTableView.beginUpdates()
    ingredientsTableViewHeight.constant = ingredientsTableView.contentSize.height
    ingredientsTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

IB Outlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dayPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var ingredientsTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var ingredientsTableViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var viewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

TableView:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ingredientsArray.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IngredientsCell", for: indexPath) as? IngredientsCell {
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else {
    return IngredientsCell()
    }
}
```

Here is the delegate function being called:

```
    func textFieldBeganTapped(cell: IngredientsCell) {
    let noOfRows: Int = ingredientsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)

    print(noOfRows)  //RETURNS 1//
    print(indexOfRows)  //RETURNS [0, 0]//

    if noOfRows == ingredientsArray.count { //THIS SECTION WORKS//
        ingredientsTableView.beginUpdates()
        ingredientsTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: noOfRows, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        ingredientsTableView.endUpdates()
        ingredientsTableViewHeight.constant = ingredientsTableView.contentSize.height
    }
    else if noOfRows == 1 { //THIS SECTION DOESNT//
        ingredientsTableView.beginUpdates()
        ingredientsTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        ingredientsTableView.endUpdates() // CRASHES HERE //
        ingredientsTableViewHeight.constant = ingredientsTableView.contentSize.height
        }
    }
```

This is the error it throws:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I dont have any unconnected IBOutlets, and i assume the delegate is set up correctly as it is firing. I also have another delegate being sent over (from textFieldDidEndEditing) but for clarity left it out. Let me know if it is needed. I have also tried various noOfRows and index path values which also didnt work. I tried using ingredientsTableView.reloadData(), which also didnt work.

My running theory is ive done something very obviously stupid with my logic but ive looked at it so often i just cant see it. Or that somehow it is clashing with the code in viewDidAppear or my TableView. Or that the problem is actually outside this code snippet.

for the x/y problem im trying to add a new row on click of an empty text box, but only if the previous one has text. (and also on the first click of the first text box)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a `try/catch` block and print out `error`? It would be good if you could catch that uncaught exception and get an idea why it's happening. Also, I get a lot of hits when I google "uitableview endupdates crash". Have you checked out any of those hits to see whether any of them are similar to your issue?

Comment: sorry i am a still a novice, i tried do/try/catch, but it doesnt throw , and swift cant catch an exception? (objective c has it just not swift) Tell me if im wrong i just googled and thats what i found. Just wanted to write back. Also i did google that before posting, im sure the answer is there somewhere, but i usually google far too much before posting here

Comment: See my comments on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, i stop getting the error if i add a value to my array. So i assume it has something to do with a mismatch between my tableView which is loaded based on my array. I will update here when i know more.

EDIT/UPDATE:

So the problem was (as discussed in the comments below and as far as i understand it) my:
`ingredientsarray.count + 1` was causing issues in my `else if noOfRows == 1` as the tableView datasource (my array) was not the same as the number of rows therefore throwing an error - the error was just thrown later on and not straight away and therefore not obvious to myself (as i thought it was working).

However i fixed it in a slightly different way as to suggested - possibly a hack job. Instead of creating 2 or even 3 custom cells and a lot of delegates i simply added some text "blank" into the array in viewDidLoad, then another "blank" on the first click, then whenever the text box was filled in, it would replace the blank text with whatever was typed in. Furthermore i searched the array for any leftover "blank" text before submitting to firebase. Hasnt caused any issues yet and saved me a lot of delegates/protocols.

So the idea: Have one blank cell initially, when you click it, it creates another one (2 blank cells total before entering text) and then from then on out it keep creating blanks cells, but only if you click on the last cell, and only if you have filled in the previous blank cells (otherwise you could keep creating hundreds of them)

Code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ingredientsArray.append("blank")
}

func textFieldBeganTapped(cell: IngredientsCell) {
    let noOfRows: Int = ingredientsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
    let indexOfRows: IndexPath = ingredientsTableView.indexPath(for: cell)!

    let indexOfSecondLastRow = IndexPath(row: noOfRows - 2, section: 0)
    let arrayIndexOfSecondLastRow = indexOfSecondLastRow.row

    if isFirstCellEmpty == true {
        isFirstCellEmpty = false
        ingredientsArray.append("blank")
        ingredientsTableView.beginUpdates()
        ingredientsTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: noOfRows, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        ingredientsTableView.endUpdates()
    } else if isFirstCellEmpty == false {
        if indexOfRows.row == noOfRows - 1 {
            if ingredientsArray.indices.contains(arrayIndexOfSecondLastRow) {
                    if cell.ingredientsTextField.text?.isEmpty == true {
                        ingredientsTableView.beginUpdates()
                        ingredientsArray.append("blank")
                        ingredientsTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: noOfRows, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func textFieldEndedTapped(cell: IngredientsCell, text: String) {
        if let textFieldIndexPath = self.ingredientsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: cell.center){
            let arrayNumber: Int = textFieldIndexPath.row
            if ingredientsArray.indices.contains(arrayNumber) {
                ingredientsArray[arrayNumber] = text
            } else {
                ingredientsArray.insert(text, at: arrayNumber)
            }
        }
    }
```

then use this to filter blanks before using data:

```
let mealIngredients = ingredientsArray.filter{$0 != "blank"}
```

Hope i haven't forgotten anything, and that its helpful to someone!

Comment: I think it's because you're saying `IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)` when there is only one row, because of `else if noOfRows == 1` -- I think you mean `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)`

Comment: The other one, in your `if()` -- I think that will fail too. I think `IndexPath` is zero-based, like an array.

Comment: yes that was what i thought, but it still throws the error. I guess its to do with my tableView setup? return ingredientsArray.count + 1 or something there. I think with this new find i might be able to work it out. But if you have any ideas let me know, thanks for the help also!

Comment: Yeah, `ingredientsArray.count + 1` looks suspicious. Note that the `tableView()` function there wants you to indicate how many rows there are in your table right now. Do you really have `ingredientsArray.count + 1` rows in your table at that moment, or just `ingredientsArray.count`?

Comment: the first one works, however only after i have clicked on it, then clicked away (hence increasing the array by one), but it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: i wanted there to  be one empty textbox/cell where as the ingredients array is still empty (so that the user knows to type something)

Comment: Then you'd have to create another cell. You can't tell `tableView()` that you have more rows than are really in the table. The system calls that function precisely to find out how many rows you (really) have.

Comment: yes i think this sounds right. will try adding a second cell and rework the logic. Will post a clean answer later if it works. Or if you submit as an answer and it works ill upvote it. Thanks very much for the help.